# popup with select box outlook vba

Tags: vba, outlook

How would I make a popup with a couple select boxes (drop downs) with outlook vba..  I need to use that value selected in the select boxes to populate a select box on a website (already populating some text fields with this script)

My script works off the currently selected mailitem and launches IE and prepopulates 2 text fields and a textarea with the sender name, subject, and e-mail body... Now I want it to populate a couple select boxes and submit the form so you just don't see IE anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to make a userform.

In the VBE, insert a UserForm.
Add the desired controls and any code you want.

Just launch the userform from you already existing code. Like this `[UserformName].Show` where UserformName will be substituted with the actual name... usually UserForm1.

Comment: Thanks man.. how do I call the selected values in the user form later in my existing code?

Comment: Also do I need a Dim line? I made a simple label and checkbox and when i put [userformname] I get an error "Invalid use of property"

Comment: UserformName.ControlName.Value If you are having problems getting your code to work, provide the code. Here is a [tutorial for making a userform](http://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm01.html). (It's for Excel, but all but the internal code applies.)

Comment: okay so.. i just added my code to a command button on the userform.. I could not get [userform1] to work within my vba code...... also I am heaving mega problems with adding items to my combobox.